# Adding a ssh key to an GCP instance using terraform works but shows error on the console

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I am adding ssh-keys to my gce instance using this:

```
ssh-keys  = "${var.ssh_user_name}:${var.ssh_pub_key}"
```

ssh_pub_key is the public key output variable of tls_private_key module which dynamically generates ssh-keys.

According to GCP ssh-key format , at the end of public key , user name should be appended but generating dynamic keys using `tls_private_key`  resource will not add the user name

After adding the ssh-keys , I am able to login to gcp instance using the private key but if I try to edit on gcp console I get the following error:

> "The SSH key is in the wrong format"

This is due to user name not being added at the end
My problem is :

```
ssh-keys  = "${var.ssh_user_name}:${var.ssh_pub_key}"
```

Shouldn't this be taking care of that? Is there another way to do this? If the ssh-key is really wrong then ssh shouldn't even be allowed . I have searched for all ways to add ssh-key at instance level in GCP through terraform, I am not able to find anything else

```
ssh-keys  = "${var.ssh_user_name}:${var.ssh_pub_key}"
```

The var.ssh_pub_key has extra `\n` line character at the end and I cannot modify this is the output variable of key generation module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So user name is required in public key - not in private. So what about something simple like

`"${var.ssh_user_name}:${var.ssh_pub_key} ${var.ssh_user_name}"` - now terraform interpolation should make your public key in proper format

Edit:
So solution for \n character at the end in pure terraform is:

```
locals {
  ssh_pub_key_without_new_line = "${replace(var.ssh_pub_key, "\n", "")}"
}
```

And then

`"${var.ssh_user_name}:${local.ssh_pub_key_without_new_line} ${var.ssh_user_name}"`

Comment: Yeah , i tried taht but teh problem is that the output of tls_private_key , public_key_openssh has extra \n line character so the user name is added in the next line

Comment: I modified answer to solve also that problem - I would appreciate if you could accept it if it actually solves your problem :)

Comment: @JakubBujny hi can you please tell me how can i ssh to my gcp machine using terraform in order to run a script i tried generate a key using (both public and private) and give the path to resourse but using this i wont executed my script can you please tell me how can i run